# Possible to Schedule a Cron Job for Specific Day of Every Month on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

**Question**
Is it possible to schedule a cron job on google app engine to run on the 27th day of every month?

**Background**
Looking at their syntax [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html), it appears doing that is too specific, but I wanted to see if anyone here managed to do it somehow.

Interestingly enough, this works:

```
 1st day of jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec 00:00
```

but this doesn't:

```
27th day of jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sep,oct,nov,dec 00:00
```

All I did was change the day number (ordinal), but it seems that if the ordinal is greater than 5, you get an exception (Parent module 'antlr3' not loaded). I assume this is because the parser is mistakenly letting the "1st day" get through thinking it means "weekday of the month" or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep it simple, stupid ! ;)

```
27 of month 9:40
```

Tested and worked.

Comment: It's been a few years, but thanks for this answer. Do you recall if this syntax was available in c. 2010 App Engine? =)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: This answer is obsolete; see new accepted answer.

It appears this currently is not possible, though I still don't know for certain.

Thus, my work around is to setup a cronjob to run every day, and have the method it's calling return early if it's not the 27th.  ~29 extra requests per month isn't that bad, right?

Comment: You probably mean "~29 extra requests per **month**"?

Comment: @Ser has the correct answer to this question. (I too confirm that it works)

Comment: Aaron - Thanks - at the time I asked, I'm not sure that syntax was available. I have unaccepted my answer and accepted his.